# How to define 2D array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have to make a 2D array that carries the information of a table

I can't find the syntax error in the following

```
int majorPositions[][]={{0,90,-90},{90,15,90},{-45,-30,30},{0,60,0}};
```

also, how do I enter last column details as it is a char, not an integer

Comment: If you're going to stick with integers, encode the on/off as 1/0.  Alternatively, create a structure type with elements x, y, z and tool — which need not all be integers.  This would have an additional advantage; you'd only need a 1D array (of structures), not a 2D array (of integers).

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the size of the array like so:

```
int majorPositions[][3]={{0,90,-90},{90,15,90},{-45,-30,30},{0,60,0}};
```

or

```
int majorPositions[4][3]={{0,90,-90},{90,15,90},{-45,-30,30},{0,60,0}};
```

If your last column is just ON/OFF, cant you just represent it as a 1 or 0?

Comment: no i cant replace it. coz 0 and 1 are TRUE and FALSE in my code

Comment: Sorry, my bad...0 is False and 1 is True. i just mistyped it

Comment: Like Jonathan said, a structure would be a good choice. You will be able to name the struct variables X,Y,Z,Tool to make it easier for others to understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the size of inner array as following.

```
int majorPositions[][3]={{0,90,-90},{90,15,90},{-45,-30,30},{0,60,0}};
```

And, I think you can encode ON and OFF into 1 and 0.

Comment: 0 and 1 are FALSE and TRUE in my code...being used for something else. any other suggestion?

Comment: @Gurjotkaur: Since ON and OFF are separate from TRUE and FALSE, there's no problem using 1 and 0 for ON and OFF, as well as using 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE (but 0 for TRUE and 1 for FALSE is completely anti-idiomatic C).  You could use `enum ToolAttached { OFF = 0, ON = 1 }` and then `enum ToolAttached tool;` as part of a structure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler after defining ON AND OFF as 1 and 0. the code: int majorPositions[4][4]={{0,90,-90,OFF},{90,15,90,ON},{-45,-30,30,ON},{0,60,0,OFF}}; is also syntax error

Comment: @Gurjotkaur There should be some info displayed along with that error.

Comment: @Gurjotkaur you can use 1/0 for ON/OFF AND TRUE/FALSE. There is no issue with that. The context in which the values are used determines whether it is representing TRUE/FALSE or ON/OFF.

Comment: Without seeing what you've done with `ON` and `OFF`, it isn't easy to guess what's wrong.  Maybe you wrote `#define OFF 0;` with the semicolon at the end.  That semicolon should not be there because it leads to inscrutable syntax errors.

Comment: @Gurjotkaur just like the numbers 1-100 can be used to represent the age of a person and also their weight in Kgs, you can use the same number combination to represent two different quantities.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like (like the other mention above)

```
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
   bool Tool;
} TableEntry_t;

TableEntry_t majorPositions[4];
```

It´s a clear solution and you can easily extend the table if you want.

Comment: If you `#include <stdbool.h>` you could use `bool` as a type and `true` and `false` as values. I'd never define booleans myself. This header was introduced 20 years ago in C99.

Comment: Using a struct will probably lead to less efficient code though. The compiler is going to pad that bool to alignment anyway.

Comment: You can avoid this when you add `__attribute__ ((packed))`. In this case the compiler don´t pad (if the compiler uses a padding). If the compiler doesn´t pad you don´t need this.

Comment: The compiler doesn't pad for fun; it does so because the code will be more efficient than if it is unpadded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type out the inner dimension size(s) explicitly. To simplify everything, consider taking advantage of the fact that booleans in C are just glorified integers. You can use an `int` as `bool` and vice versa.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int majorPositions[][4]=
{
  {  0,  90, -90, false },
  { 90,  15,  90, true  },
  {-45, -30,  30, true  },
  {  0,  60,   0, false },
};
```

You can get the size of this array at compile-time using `sizeof(majorPositions)/sizeof(majorPositions[0])` (which will be 4 in this case).

Alternatively use a `struct` as proposed in other answers. It may or may not give less efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

In two dimensional arrays, you must specify second dimension of an array during the declaration.

`int majorPositions[][3]={{0,90,-90},{90,15,90},{-45,-30,30},{0,60,0}};`